# Replacing the nth character, only if is a given symbol

Tags: sed

I am new on sed and I am trying to replace the nth character of a line, only if is a symbol "-"

for example, replace the 4th position for an "X" only if is "-":

```
aaabbbccc

aaa-bbddd

aaa-cccbb
```

to get:

```
aaabbbccc

aaaXbbddd

aaaXcccbb
```

I found that is possible to replace the nth position with this command:
sed 's/^(.{3}).(.*)/\1X\2/' but I am not able to incorporate the given condition (only if is a given symbol)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 echo "aaabbbccc
aaa-bbddd
aaa-cccbb"|sed -r 's/^(.{3})-(.*)$/\1X\2/'
```

output:

```
aaabbbccc
aaaXbbddd
aaaXcccbb
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's/^\(.\{3\}\)-/\1X/' file
```

Or

```
sed '/^.\{3\}-/s/./X/4' file
```